# Locked out after backup

Tags: backup

Befor I forget, I use Magento 1.9.2.1.
I backuped my live Magento shop. Then I copied the backup to my test shop an loaded the backup. Now I cant reach the frontend or the backend. I'm always beeing redirected to the live Shop. I believe its because of the address set up in the shop. Where are they beeing saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change in core_config_data table.

https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Update+Site+URL+in+core_config_data+after+you+move+to+a+new+server+or+change+domains

How to change base_url settings with mysql from the command line:

find your configuration:

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

edit your configuration:

```
update core_config_data set value = '/new.domain.com/' where config_id = ID;
```

with `ID` from above.

Comment: Thank fschmengler for the link. I changed everything, but still cant get on the front or backend. I checked if my browser is the problem, but any browser is going strait on the active shop. Backend login starts correct, but after login, i'm on the active shop. Not loged in of course.

Comment: OK, I just worked a little further. I got the shop so far, that I remain on the proper Domain. But he doubles the domainname. Like www.imdump.xyz/imdump.xyz/

Comment: Me .... again ;)
Followed the instructions from here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240518/after-magento-move-to-another-server-skin-css-not-working]
Now the shop is working finaly again. Thanks for the help!!!!